# Accessing HttpServletRequest inside ActionListener

Tags: jsf, weblogic, portlet, jsf-1.2

I have an `ActionListener` for a JSF  button as follows,

```
<h:commandButton id="id1" action="#{Mybean.Submit}" value="Click">
    <f:actionListener binding="#{Mybean.actionListenerImpl}" type="bean.ActionListenerImpl" />
</h:commandButton>
```

The `ActionListener` is implemented as follows,

```
public void processAction(ActionEvent event) throws AbortProcessingException {
    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest)fc.getExternalContext().getRequest();
    PortletBackingContext pbc = PortletBackingContext.getPortletBackingContext(req);
    pbc.fireCustomEvent("test", "test");
}
```

But this is throwing the follwing exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.bea.portlet.container.ActionRequestImpl cannot be cast to javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
    at bean.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:18)
```

I need access to `HttpServletRequest` to get `PortletBackingContext` object through which I can fire a custom event.

I am using JSF 1.2 in weblogic 10.3.0

Comment: You're running JSF on a portlet container instead of on a servlet container. Why exactly did you expect it to return a servlet request instead of a portlet request? You'd better reframe your question like as "How to I get the current instance of the PortletBackingContext in a JSF managed bean?" instead of asking how to achieve an impossible solution (well, assuming that you can't plainly change the portlet container to a servlet container like Tomcat/JBoss/Glassfish).

Comment: But to get PortletBackingContext, we need to pass HttpServletRequest as an argument. Is there any other way to get PortletBackingContext from JSF bean?

Comment: I got HttpServletRequest by accessing "javax.servlet.request of ActionRequest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got HttpServletRequest by accessing "javax.servlet.request of ActionRequest.

Comment: HttpServletRequest Req = (javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request");